# Skip incompressible files

Tags: compression

Is there a compression tool which doesn't attempt to compress incompressible files in order to reduce the compression time? It would need operate on a folder (rather than on a single tar file), and it would try compressing each file, and give up if it doesn't make much progress. By 'give up' I mean switch to lowest compression level for that file.

Comment: What's your OS?

Comment: Agreed with slhck. On Windows, it is really easy to do this. Just use "compress.exe", and you can set WHAT to compress. Compress text, log files, etc. Done.

Comment: Similar (Dupe?): [How to avoid compressing compressed files](http://superuser.com/questions/92076/how-to-avoid-compressing-compressed-files)

Answer (score 2):

Curiously there is [AutoCompress](http://www.steelbytes.com/?mid=21)

> AutoCompress scans files evaluating their compressibility (or current compression ratio), and **compresses them (or decompresses them) if they meet certain criteria;** namely the date since modification, **compression ratio,** and file size.

<sup>ps: I have no idea what the author means by "decompress them if they meet criteria"</sup>
Update: There is also a note saying "compress using NTFS compression" on an earlier page -- not sure if we are even discussing standard file-compression here.

In general, I think that 'compressibility' of a file might be estimated with some methods but they would imply extra time-overhead. There should however be ways to code the compressor so that it will 'bail-out' and just archive the file as-is with a mark describing that on it. While I like the idea, I've not yet seen this.